# If you're in the top ____% ______ (ex. Jeff Atwood is in the top 0.03% overall), do you see it if you click on your own profile?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I've never seen it, but in this last week (yesterday and today, really), I've gained 49 reputation; meaning I would've expected to see something similar to the example in the title of [Jeff Atwood's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) whatever-you-call-it. I have a feeling that it's only if you're past a certain reputation, do other people see it, but this made me even more questioning if I would see that same thing on my own profile if I was signed in looking at my profile.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think you need to have at least 200 reputation for it to count you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Catija mentioned in the comments, you need 200 rep to start showing up in the [reputation leagues.](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta) That's why you're not seeing this on your profile. In the right hand side bar, under the charts breaking down users by rep, you'll see the following note:

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

To answer your direct question, I also don't see this on your profile, but I do see it on mine.

The banner shows you what your current highest ranking in the leagues are. For Jeff, it's 0.03% overall. For me, it's 9% this quarter.