# Why do I not have the 5/5 for the Curious badge?

Tags: support, bug, questions, badges

I'm pretty sure that I have asked 5 (really 6) well-received questions on this site, my questions are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/384016/thejavanub?tab=questions), but for some reason, I don't have the 5 separate days of asking a good question.
Why is this? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've asked two questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306962/if-youre-in-the-top-ex-jeff-atwood-is-in-the-top-0-03-overall), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306944/when-a-person-chooses-to-make-their-question-answer-community-wiki-does-it-show)) on February 13th, so that counts as one day. [Closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307433/why-does-sos-community-feel-a-lot-harsher-than-any-of-the-other-communities), even duplicates, don't count either. That's why you're still on 4/5, but this question was on its way to bring you on 5/5
<sub>(except that it's now marked as a duplicate, because it *is* possible to derive this all from the information in the FAQ. I do understand where your confusion comes from.)</sub>